# AngularJS controller is called twice (with no ui.router)

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, controller, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a problem with a controller in AngularJS, it's called twice and it reset my array messages... I want create a simple chat box where a user srite a message, click send and in a div I show all messages...

This is my index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="theme.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.5/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="local_functions.js"></script>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Chat v0.1</title>
</head>
<body ng-app="myApp">

        <h1>Welcome in Chat v0.1</h1>
        <div ng-include="'myChat.html'"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

This is myChat.html:

```
<div class="chat" ng-controller="myController">

  <h2>Chat altro utente</h2>
  <div class="chatbox">
    Messaggi inviati:
    <div ng-repeat="message in listChatMessages">
      <div>Messaggio: {{message.text}}</div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <form class="messageForm" action="index.html" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="msg" value="" placeholder="Write a message..." ng-model="messageText" autocofucs="autocofucs"/>
    <input type="submit" name="sendMsg" value="Invia" ng-click="sendMessage()"/>
  </form>

</div>
```

And this is my local_functions.js:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.factory('chatService', function() {
    var lastMessage = "";

    return {
        getMessage : function() {
            return lastMessage;
        },
        setMessage : function(messages, msg) {
            messages.push({
                text: msg,
            });
            lastMessage = msg;
        }
    };
});

myApp.controller('myController', function($scope, chatService) {
    $scope.messageText = "";
    $scope.listChatMessages = [];

    $scope.sendMessage = function() {
        chatService.setMessage($scope.listChatMessages, $scope.messageText);
        $scope.messageText = "";
    };
});
```

Array messages.push has the right value and I see the valuee in chat box but after some millisecond controller is loaded again and it restore the listChatMessages with $scope.listChatMessages = [];

Anyone can help me? Thanks in advice!

Code download:
zip file: http://wikisend.com/download/780620/AngularJSControllerTwice.zip
war file: http://wikisend.com/download/635060/AngularJS-Chat.war

Comment: why is your controller named myController instead of anotherChatController

Comment: change it, I semplified my example with simple names ;)

Comment: Are you dealing with server. Or just you are working on client?

Comment: With a server (Eclipse with Tomcat v8), but it's the same if I open the file directly on browser...

Comment: can you create a plunker for this? couldn't recreate the scenario that you are having to solve it.

Comment: I added zip and war file link in my question :)

Comment: i ain't working with eclipse @Alex, check out this plunker i have created. Why do you have action="index.html".http://plnkr.co/edit/7qb93cb2utIEYmmvg2Zy?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

in local_functions.js

change :

```
myApp.controller('myController', function($scope, chatService)
```

to:

```
myApp.controller('anotherChatController', function($scope, chatService)
```

Comment: I semplified my example with simple names, this it not the error :(

Answer (score 0):

```
<form class="messageForm" action="index.html" method="post">
<input type="text" name="msg" value="" placeholder="Write a message..." ng-model="messageText" autocofucs="autocofucs"/>
<input type="submit" name="sendMsg" value="Invia" ng-click="sendMessage()"/></form>
```

Try

```
<form class="messageForm" ng-submit="sendMessage()">
<input type="text" name="msg" value="" placeholder="Write a message..." ng-model="messageText">
<input type="submit" name="sendMsg" value="Invia"> </form>
```

See https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSubmit

Answer (score 0):

try as below by putting  $scope.listChatMessages = [] in ng-init of div in chat.html file;

```
 <div class="chat" ng-controller="myController" ng-init="listChatMessages = []">

<h2>Chat altro utente</h2>
<div class="chatbox">
Messaggi inviati:
<div ng-repeat="message in listChatMessages">
  <div>Messaggio: {{message.text}}</div>
</div>
```

```
 var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.factory('chatService', function() {
var lastMessage = "";

return {
    getMessage : function() {
        return lastMessage;
    },
    setMessage : function(messages, msg) {
        messages.push({
            text: msg,
        });
        lastMessage = msg;
    }
 };
 });

 myApp.controller('myController', function($scope, chatService) {
$scope.messageText = "";

$scope.sendMessage = function() {
    chatService.setMessage($scope.listChatMessages, $scope.messageText);
    $scope.messageText = "";
};
});
```